# Access Azure VM using Domain name with DNS in external Service

Tags: azure, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

[image]

I have domain name registered in SmarterASP with SSL and was using for apps hosted with them.

Now i have Azure VM with static Ip (say 23.12.12.xx) , i can access http server with the IP Address , Now i want to use the domain registered in SmarterAsp on sites hosted in the VM instead if the ip address

i changed the ip address in A record to be 23.12.12.xx (see image above), now when i visit the domain it shows nothing , if i ping , it resolved to the ip address but i cannot access my VM Web server with the domain name ,

is there any firewall setting i need to change in Azure or inside the VM ,
or do i need to setup DNS inside the VM 
or use azure DNZ zones.

Comment: Does it really "show nothing" or some error is returned?

Comment: it shows timeout

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could verify if your web server is binding with the host name(domain name) instead of the IP address. If you have done so, you could try to restart your Azure VM.

For example, when you are using IIS.

1. Open IIS (Click WIN+R, enter inetmgr in the dialog and click OK. Alternatively, search for IIS Manger in start window).
2. Expand the Server node and then expand Sites folder.
3. Click on the Website that you want to access using a domain name and then click on Bindings in the Actions pane.

For more reference, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/

Comment: The domain has SSL , if i select Https in binding i have to provide a certificate which is not on my VM but in SmarterAsp.net , if i bind with http it shows timeout

Comment: When you `nslookup` your domain name like `www.abc.com`, it will resolve your Azure VM Public IP address? Do you have a A or CNAME record which maps domain name to 23.12.12.xx? When you bind with hostname, have you tried to restart the service or Azure VM?

Comment: If currently, you could access the websites via Azure VM public IP but the domain name, you should wait for [DNS propagation time](https://www.siteground.com/kb/what_is_dns_propagation_and_why_it_takes_so_long/). `A DNS change requires up to 72 hours to propagate worldwide, although most often this happens in a matter of hours.`